# Using nginx to redirect port 80 to port 9000 in Play! app

Tags: nginx, playframework, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, playframework-2.2

I have a play app that I now access at playapp.com:9000 but I want to be able to access it at playapp.com. It doesn't really matter how I do this but I think I want to use nginx (but I'm open to other suggestions).

I've added the following to nginx.conf:

```
...
upstream playapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
...

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://playapp/$1$is_args$args;
    }
...
```

It does redirect to the right place but the CSS doesn't seem to work and the JS seems to contain html for some reason (which causes the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ").

Is there something else I need to add to get the right location for these other files? When I look at sources in developer tools, I can see all the CSS and JS files are there but they just contain the contents of my main.scala.html

Answer (score 0):

1) Set root for `server{...}`

2) Set location for static files, something like:

```
location ~* \.(txt|ico|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|swf|pdf|htm|html|woff|htc)$ {
    expires 31d;
    access_log off;
}
```

Place this location right after `location / {...}`

Comment: The static files are working now, but if I change the server from "127.0.0.1:9000" to "playapp.com:9000" it doesn't work anymore. How would I point it to an external server?